# com.dropbox.core.NetworkIOException: Software caused connection abort

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

My users see the following error:

```
com.dropbox.core.NetworkIOException: Software caused connection abort 
  Caused by java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort
```

Does anyone know what are the reasons for this issue and how to fix this?

Does this simply signify that there is no Internet connection?